# Sequence of functions such that the sequence is not Riemann integrable, but the limiting function is?

Tags: integration, analysis

> Give an example of a sequence of functions $\{f_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}},\ x\in [0,1]$ such that $f_n$ is not Riemann integrable, but the limiting function is.

I have no idea where to start with this. The sequences I keep thinking of are all Riemann integrable.

Comment: The Dirichlet function that takes the value 1 at irrationals and 0 at rationals is not Riemann integrable. Now make a sequence out of that that converges to the identically 0 function.

Answer (score 3):

If you have one non-integrable function $f$, then you can use $f_n=\frac{1}{n}f$, so the limit is the zero function, which is certainly integrable.

Do you know of any function that is not Riemann integrable?

Answer (score 2):

Try

$$f_n(x)=\begin{cases}
1/n\text{,} &\text{if }x\in \Bbb{Q}\\
0\text{,} &\text{if }x\in \Bbb{R}
\end{cases}$$